# android : volley respose is 200 but onResponse is never called

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to make a POST jsonObject request; which gives me a jsonObject in response,
 the responseCode is 200 and my server receives the data successfully. but onResponse is never called and I cannot catch the jsonObject in response.

any idea how to solve this issue ?

I use the following code for the task:

```
JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("url",Url);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest req= new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url, obj,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            return headers;
        }
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

Comment: Where is the response code that you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Delete this code:

```
@Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
    }
```